# Dart HttpRequest POST process doesn't survive function calls

Tags: http, dart, https

I've got a Dart server that receives a POST request, if I read the POST body immediately with `await utf8.decoder.bind(request).join()`, I get the contents without issue.  If I pass the HttpRequest to a function to process the body with the identical code, I get an HttpException: `HttpException: Connection closed while receiving data, uri = /v1/auth/apple`.  I don't have any control over the POST as it's sent to my server from the Apple authentication server as a redirectURI.  Why does passing the HttpRequest to a function cause this to fail?

The POST body is a URL Encoded string.

**Dart SDK version: 2.12.0-141.0.dev (dev)**

Here is the basic router:

```dart
void route(HttpServer httpsServer) async {
    await for (HttpRequest request in httpsServer) {
      switch (request.method) {
        case 'GET':
          _getRouter.route(request);
          break;
        case 'POST':
          if (request.uri.path == '/v1/auth/apple') {
            // If I execute this function, the POST processing fails
            // with the HttpException
            postTest(request);
            // If I execute the identical code from the function inline here
            // then it reads the body of the POST without issue
            var requestBody = await utf8.decoder.bind(request).join();
            var requestUri = Uri(query: requestBody);
            _getRouter.v1Auth(request, uri: requestUri);
          } else {
            _postRouter.route(request);
          }
          break;
        default:
          request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.methodNotAllowed;
      }
      await request.response.flush();
      await request.response.close();
    }

// Attempting to process the POST body in this function causes
// an HttpExeception: Connection closed while receiving data
void postTest(HttpRequest request) async {
    var requestBody = await utf8.decoder.bind(request).join();
    var requestUri = Uri(query: requestBody);
    _getRouter.v1Auth(request, uri: requestUri);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not `await`ing your async function `postTest`. `postTest` should really be returning `Future<void>` instead of void.

Then you can `await postTest(request);` properly.

There should be some linter rules that you can enable to warn you when you're not await a future in an async function and that can enforce all async functions to return futures.

You can read more about customizing static analysis [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file). I think the specific [rules](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/) you're looking for are `avoid_void_async` and `unawaited_futures`.

Comment: Well, I feel silly as heck on this.  I stared at this for hours and never saw it.  Thank you!

Comment: @MartinFink Not a problem. I really wish those linter rules I mentioned should always be enabled by default because it can get kinda confusing.

Comment: linter rules?  Link?  I'll go enable them for sure!  Thanks again.

Comment: @MartinFink Made an edit with some links for info on customizing static analysis.